# React Native Spinner Activity Indicator not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is Code but not  working for me.

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
    <ActivityIndicator
      animating={true}
      size='large'
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Can you please add more pieces of information to your problem, like your `ActivityIndicator`, `spinnerStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This styling is for showing `ActivityIndicator` on center of page.

```
<View style={{
     display:"flex",
     flex:1,
     justifyContent:"center",
     alignItems:"center"
  }}>
    <ActivityIndicator
      animating={true}
      size='large'
    />
  </View>
```